# Why is this ListView null?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm completing part of the Google Android Tutorial ([this part](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1v4Kv5lSd8-4cs0BW6F24ccA3c1-KDQZG3EV49CUHQys/pub?embedded=true#h.uckrb0yv2r11) to be precise) and I've hit a snag. I'm trying to set the Adapter of a ListView to a custom ArrayAdapter. Unfortunately, findViewById seems to be returning null (which means I can't set the adapter).

Here's the relevant code:

**MainActivityFragment**

```
private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private ArtistItemAdapter artistsAdapter;

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    artistsAdapter = new ArtistItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_artist, new Pager<Artist>().items);

    ListView artistsList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewArtists);
    artistsList.setAdapter(artistsAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    EditText searchBar = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);

    searchBar.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        ArtistsPager artists;

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                FetchArtistsTask artistsTaskCall = new FetchArtistsTask();
                artistsTaskCall.execute(String.valueOf(v.getText()));
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
}
```

**MainActivity.onCreate()**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:hint="Search Artist"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewArtists"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.android.spotifyproject.MainActivityFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**LogCat:** http://pastebin.com/CUNF05Af

Comment: ... `List` is null,  not `ListView` ... **obviously** `new Pager<Artist>().items` is null

Comment: Which findViewById() returns null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the ListView that is null, it's the data you sent into the Adapter when you created it, so when you try to set the Adapter on the ListView it calls List.size() on the data(null), and that's where the error is.